# How long has Daredevils of Sassoun been considered a national epic of the Armenians?

Tags: history-of-literature, armenian-language

[*Daredevils of Sassoun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevils_of_Sassoun) (or *Sasna Dzrer* or *Sasna cṙer*) is an Armenian heroic epic that "is commonly cited as one of the most important works of Armenian folklore". Its main character is [David of Sassoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_of_Sassoun), whom Wikipedia describes as "the main hero of Armenia's national epic Daredevils of Sassoun, who drove Arab invaders out of Armenia".

The epic circulated as oral literature from the 8th century and wasn't put into written form in 1873 by Garegin Srvandztiants. Since Armenia had a rather eventful history in the decades that followed ([Armenian genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_genocide) during World War I, several armed conflicts during the brief existence of the [First Republic of Armenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Republic_of_Armenia), [Sovietisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_Soviet_Socialist_Republic#Sovietization), [Stalinist purges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_victims_of_the_Great_Purge)), I wonder when the epic managed to establish itself as a national epic. During the brief period between 1873 and the Armenian genocide? During (and perhaps because of) the Armenian genocide? At a later point? The information on Wikipedia provides no information about this.

Comment: It seems ([judging from a very bad translation](https://hy-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/%D5%8D%D5%A1%D5%BD%D5%B6%D5%A1_%D5%AE%D5%BC%D5%A5%D6%80?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=tr)) that the [Armenian Wikipedia page](https://hy.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D5%8D%D5%A1%D5%BD%D5%B6%D5%A1_%D5%AE%D5%BC%D5%A5%D6%80) also doesn't answer this question.

Comment: A [UNESCO Translation Program book](https://books.google.com.tr/books?hl=en&lr=&id=OrorAQAAIAAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA2&dq=daredevils+of+sassoun+became+armenian+national+epic&ots=IMWOojqzgT&sig=iS19qtrL1-CT4dULtj4sfALoDho&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=daredevils%20of%20sassoun%20to%20remind&f=false) claims that *Daredevils of Sassoun* "largely escaped the historians and monkish chroniclers of later Armenia because they became part of the vulgar superstitions of the people. The heroes lived underground, as it were, in traditional folklore."